# Are there any different proof of the uncountability of $[0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

How many ways out there to prove $[0, 1]$ with is uncountable?

1. Proof by the famous Cantor's diagonal argument :

There is no onto function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $[0, 1]$.

Suppose, $f:\mathbb{N} \to [0, 1]$ be any function.

For any $n\in \mathbb{N} $ define

\begin{align}a_n=\Bigg \{ &2 :\text{if the nth decimal place of} f(n)≠2\\
&3 : otherwise\\
\end{align}

$x=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{a_n}{10^n}$

Then, $x \in [0, 1]$ but $x\notin f(\mathbb{N}) $

2. Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \ell(\mathbb{R}), \lambda) $ , then $[0, 1]$ is Lebesgue Measurable with Lebesgue measure $\ell([0, 1]=1>0$

Hence, $[0, 1]$ is uncountable.

3. $[0, 1]$ as a metric subspace of $(R, d_{euclidean}) $ is a complete metric space without any isolated point.

Then by Baire Catagory theorem, $[0, 1]$ must be uncountable.

Are there any different proof of the uncountability of $[0, 1]$?

Comment: How do you characterize “interesting”?

Comment: I mean different.

Comment: I’m guessing 1) covers any proof that involves showing the existence of a bijection between $[0,1]$ and some other uncountable set? For example, you can show that there is a bijection between the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ and a subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Worth mentioning is the fact that any proper $\sigma$-ideal of subsets of the reals that contains every singleton set provides such an example, and each of the three examples you gave is such an example (namely, the $\sigma$-ideals of the countable sets, the Lebesgue measure zero sets, and the first category sets). I'm not entirely sure off-hand, but I strongly suspect there are $2^{2^c} = 2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}$ many such $\sigma$-ideals of subsets of $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of Cantor's original proof that given an interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ and a sequence $\{x_k\}$ of real numbers, there is at least one number $c\in (\alpha,\beta)$ that is not in the sequence.

First find two elements of the sequence $x_{k_1}$ and $x_{k_2}$ with the smallest subscripts such that $x_{k_1} < x_{k_2}$ and $x_{k_1},x_{k_2}\in(\alpha,\beta)$ and denote them $A_1$ and $B_1$. If no such elements exist we are done as we can easily find such a $c$. Then

1. $\alpha < A_1 < B_1 < \beta$.
2. If $x_k\in(A_1,B_1)$ we must have $k\geq 3$.

Iterate this process to find sequences $A_r$ and $B_r$ of elements in the sequence $\{x_k\}$ such that

1. $\alpha < A_1 < A_2 < \cdots < A_r < B_r < \cdots < B_2 < B_1 < \beta $.
2. If $x_k\in (A_r,B_r)$ then $k \geq 2r +1$.

Again, if this process cannot be continued at any step then we have an interval with at most $1$ point of the sequence and can easily find a number in that interval that isn't among the $x_k$. So we may assume that the process can be continued indefinitely. This leads to an infinite sequence of nested closed intervals

$$[A_1,A_2]\supset [A_2,B_2]\supset\cdots$$

Such a sequence always has at least one point in its intersection, call it $c$. Suppose now that $c=x_N$ for some natural number $N$. Then it must be that $x_N\in(A_N,B_N)$, but by construction this implies

$$N \geq 2N+1$$

which is a contradiction.

Sources

1. [Über unendliche, lineare Punktmannigfaltigkeiten](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-7091-9516-1)
2. [The Calculus Gallery](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691182858/the-calculus-gallery)